# How to enable vertical scroll when more data is loaded in the sub component in form of gridcontrols?

Tags: angular

When i am opening the component there is a sub component that gets array of data objects through api. I need to enable scroll-vertical when the data returned is more than 5 and disable it when  the data objects are less than 5.

Comment: use ngStyle with condition to overflow-y property or you can use ngClass with condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wcotd

basic idea is to use [ngClass] with condition

```
<div [ngClass]="{'temp':items.length > 5}">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>

<button (click)="add(3)" >Add</button>
<button (click)="remove()" >Remove</button>
```

And in css :

```
.temp{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```